# Jquery Mobile onSearch event handler

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

i'm using jquery mobile with phoneGap for creating a application in android.

In HTML5 standards, 
`<input type='search' onsearch='searchHandler()'>`

But the search event is not triggered ?

Is it because i'm using in mobile.

Is there any other way to use that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to the `change` event to make sure you capture the search string after the user is done typing it:

```
$('input[type="search"]').on('change', function (event) {
    //the user has changed the value and de-focused the element or submitted the search
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w9Bdg/1/

Note that `.on()` is new as of jQuery 1.7 and if you are using an older version it's the same in this case as `.bind()`.

Comment: Frankly I can't get user behavior for this code and example. You have search field in mobile app. You can type something there.. and how to fire this event? On PC I pressed "Enter" but how can I trigger this event in mobile app?

Comment: @RredCat The `change` event should fire when the user clicks outside of the search box. For for instance, if they click a "Search" button, that should change the focused element and trigger the `change` event on the text-input. You could also bind to the `click` event of a button.

Comment: I got it. But I've not seen nice located search button in any examples. So for me best way is `afterkeyup` event.